# iOS build failed after adding cordova fabric plugin

Tags: ios, ionic3, google-fabric

I added fabric plugin in my ionic 3 app. It's working in android but for iOS it has a problem.
When running `ionic build ios --prod` or `ionic build ios` I am getting following error:

```
/Users/abc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-
fgpvbdhjneqliicfyhoiuvrrhbfs/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-
iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Script-FE794D9BFDB14C30B9E39200.sh: line 2: 
/Users/abc/Desktop/NS: No such file or directory
```

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:

```
PhaseScriptExecution Fabric.io:\ Crashlytics 
/Users/abc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-
fgpvbdhjneqliicfyhoiuvrrhbfs/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-
iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Script-FE794D9BFDB14C30B9E39200.sh
(1 failure)

Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -
xcconfig,/Users/abc/Desktop/NS H iOS 2/platforms/ios/cordova/build-
debug.xcconfig,-workspace,MyApp.xcworkspace,-scheme,MyApp,-
configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS 
Simulator,name=iPhone 
5s,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/abc/Desktop/NS H iOS 
2/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/abc/Desktop/NS H 
iOS 2/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

Ionic info:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.10.2
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.1 Build version 8E1000a
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed Fabric with CocoaPods? Here is the doc: https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install (Select Objective C).

This issue seems to be similar to this one that has been solved: [Integrate Fabric/Crashlytics via CocoaPods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29071277/integrate-fabric-crashlytics-via-cocoapods)

I hope It helps you.

Comment: Thanks for response. I don't want to integrate directly from xcode as sometimes I need to remove platform iOS then all changes will be vanished & I need to do things again. BTW I have resolved this problem. It is due to my root project folder name. It contained spaces. I removed those & now working fine.